# Can you check whether these answers are valid? (analysis-power series)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

The question: Find suitable coefficients $(a_n)$ so that $\sum a_n x^n$ has the given properties or Explain why such request is impossible.

Question (a): Converges on every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ 
Question (b): Diverges on every $x \in \mathbb{R}$

The below are the (potential) answers I want to be checked and/or corrected:

[image]

[image]

** The space is strictly limited to the Euclidean one 
** For (a), it's "which converges for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$"

Comment: Both of those look solid. By a similar argument as in (b): every power series around $c$ converges at $c$.

Comment: Yes, these look good to me.

Comment: Was there any stipulation that $a_i$ must be positive? If not, yes, $a_i = 0$ certainly converges.